# How to determine using reflection the generic parameter of the base class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following structure

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass<System.Int32>
{
}
```

In a static method and without instantiating a new MyClass instance how do I get the type of the generic parameter used to build the concrete base class? e.g in the above example System.Int32

Comment: To get SO to format the code properly, select the block of code and hit CTRL+K.  I eddited the post to format the code properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
public static Type GetBaseTypeGenericArgument(Type type) {
  return type.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
}

...
GetBaseTypeGenericArgument(typeof(MyClass));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Type arg = typeof(MyClass).BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```